# twitter-bootstrap icons do not appear in heroku

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, heroku, icons

I am working on a Rails 4 application with ruby 2.0.0. I use twitter-bootstrap and I have a trouble with icon glyphs: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons
The problem is that these icons do not appear in production. In development environment, everything is ok.

This is my code in my help.html.erb file

```
<i class="icon-user"></i>
```

My gemfile contains the following line:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.1.0'
```

My production environment is deployed on heroku.
Do you have any idea why theses icons do not appear? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I solved the problem by downloading icon images directly from http://glyphicons.com/, putting them into app/assets/images, setting config.serve_static_assets to true, running rake assets:precompile, and pushing to heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by downloading icon images directly from glyphicons.com, putting them into app/assets/images, setting config.serve_static_assets to true, running rake assets:precompile, and pushing to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Try running the following:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean and
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile.
```

That worked for me.